# Pyparsing takes too long for Wikipedia custom preprocessing

Tags: parsing, nlp, data-cleaning, wikipedia, pyparsing

I'm trying to customize the corpus processing for Gensim's WikiCorpus by setting the `tokenizer_func` argument to a custom `tokenize` function:

```
# Set tokenizer to our custom tokenizer
wiki = WikiCorpus(input, tokenizer_func=tokenize)
```

But PyParsing is taking way too long to process the text (as in, a single article isn't even processed after a day of running). In my case, I want to clean the Wikipedia corpus as normal, except keeping any words that match a list of words that I have (which may contain numbers, underscores, or ampersand) unchanged.

Assuming a variable length list of words `phrase_list` that includes:
81, McDonald's, Twenty-one, Happy 10, Sam's car, Ham & Eggs

Here's some example of input to be cleaned:

> Here's some example text to convert to the cleaned text! & 8 *
> tooth-fairy 81 is a number and Mcdonald's is a fast food chain.
> What about twenty-one? That's also a number. Here are some tenses: run ran
> running.
>
> Don't know how to feel about Happy 10 but Sam's car is
> pretty okay. In-N-Out is a classic of course, sometimes people write
> In N Out though. 7-Eleven anyone? Or is it 7 Eleven? Ham & Eggs is a
> pretty interesting book too -I guess- - 5nonalpha

And the desired output:

> heres some example text to convert to the cleaned text tooth fairy 81 is
> number and mcdonalds is fast_food chain what about twenty_one thats
> also number here are some tenses run ran running dont know how to feel
> about happy_10 but sams_car is pretty okay in_n_out is classic of
> course sometimes people write in_n_out though 7_eleven anyone or is it
> 7_eleven ham_&_eggs is pretty interesting book too guess nonalpha

Note that the processing is very fast on this example text, but not on the actual Wikipedia corpus (I'm following this tutorial, but customizing it: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/11/building-wikipedia-text-corpus-nlp.html)

Here's the custom tokenizer (and some helper functions) I wrote which uses PyParsing:

```
from typing import List
from pyparsing import *
from gensim.utils import to_unicode
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus
import string
import re

TOKEN_MIN_LEN = 2
TOKEN_MAX_LEN = 30

def pre_phrase_tokenize_processing(sentence):
    """
    Helper: For cleaning sentence before phrases have been combined into single underscored tokens. Apply to entire sentence.
    Removes hyphens, and punctuation except ampersands.
    """
    # replace all hyphens with spaces since some phrases use them; just consider as multiword so they can be combined with underscore later
    sentence = sentence.translate(str.maketrans('-', ' '))
    
    # remove all punctuation except ampersands, since some phrases use them
    remove_punct = string.punctuation.replace("&", "")
    sentence = sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', remove_punct))
    
    return sentence

def turn_phrases_into_tokens(phrases, sentence):
    """
    Helper: Turns all individual phrases in a sentence into single underscored tokens according to a provided phrase dictionary.
    """
    regex = re.compile("|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(phrase) for phrase in phrases]))
    sentence = regex.sub(lambda m: phrases[m.group(0)], sentence)
    return sentence

#@traceParseAction
def post_phrase_tokenize_processing(toks):
    """
    For cleaning sentence after phrases have been combined into single underscored tokens. Apply to each non-phrase word.
    Removes numeric characters and punctuation. Note toks is a list passed by pyparsing.
    """
    # remove numeric characters, since only non-brand words are passed in
    word = re.sub(r'\d+', '', toks[0])
    
    # remove all punctuation (including &), since only non-brand words are passed in
    word = word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return word

# our phrase dictionary - actual list may continue many more phrases
phrases = {"81": "81", "mcdonalds": "mcdonalds", "twenty one": "twenty_one", "happy 10": "happy_10", "sams car": "sams_car", "ham & eggs": "ham_&_eggs"}

def tokenize(content: str, token_min_len=TOKEN_MIN_LEN, token_max_len=TOKEN_MAX_LEN, lower=True) -> List[str]:
    """Overrides original tokenize method in wikicorpus.py
    Tokenize a piece of text from Wikipedia.

    Parameters
    ----------
    content : str
        String without markup (see :func:`~gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.filter_wiki`).
    token_min_len : int
        Minimal token length.
    token_max_len : int
        Maximal token length.
    lower : bool
         Convert `content` to lower case?
    Returns
    -------
    list of str
        List of tokens from `content`.
    """
    content = to_unicode(content, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
    if lower:
        content = content.lower()
    
    content = pre_phrase_tokenize_processing(content)
    
    # Combine any phrases into single tokens
    content = turn_phrases_into_tokens(phrases, content)
    
    
    # Match either one of our phrases, or any other nonwhitespace word (in which case we process)
    phrase_list = list(phrases.values())
    parser = Combine(
        OneOrMore(
            oneOf(phrase_list, asKeyword=True)
            | Word(alphas)
            | Word(printables).setParseAction(post_phrase_tokenize_processing)
        ),
        joinString=' ',
        adjacent=False
    )
    content = parser.transformString(content)
    
    return [
        to_unicode(token) for token in content.split()
        if token_min_len <= len(token) <= token_max_len and not token.startswith('_')
    ]
```

Also just for reference, this is the actual code I'm using to call the tokenizer when I clean the Wikipedia corpus (and not the example text) - more can be found at the same tutorial above:

```
def make_corpus(in_f, out_f):
    """Convert Wikipedia xml dump file to text corpus"""

    output = open(out_f, 'w')
    
    # Set tokenizer to our custom tokenizer
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f, tokenizer_func=tokenize)

    i = 0
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 100 == 0):
            print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles')
    output.close()
    print('Processing complete!')
```

So far I'm pretty sure the problem is with PyParsing (the part where I call `parser = Combine(...)`) - rather than matching every single non-whitespace word, I should only match the words that need to be cleaned - but I'm a bit stuck on how to do this as I don't have too much experience with this library. I also have a problem with the spaces between words getting removed when they're put back together, which is why I had to call `Combine` with `joinString=' '`, so if there are any suggestions for that it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clean up your sample code. Refers to undefined names `to_unicode`, `phrases`, `phrase_list`, and `post_phrase_tokenize_processing`.

Comment: Sorry was trying to keep it concise but left out important info! The code should have more context, and I also linked the tutorial I'm basing my custom code on.

Comment: How many items are in your actual phrase_list? I think this is probably the choke point.

Comment: Ah I have about 330 phrases or so - do you have any suggestions for how I can handle this long list?

Comment: See edit added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

After commenting out the content scrubbing calls to `pre_phrase_tokenize_processing` and `turn_phrases_into_tokens` (since there was insufficient code to run them), and commenting out the parse action to `post_phrase_tokenize_processing`, this ran on my system in about 1 second.

What exactly happens in `post_phrase_tokenize_processing`?

Try running with a very small input text, and profile that parse action, to get some ideas on where to go next.

Also, you can just do some rough instrumenting of that parse action by wrapping it in the diagnostic decorator provided with pyparsing `traceParseAction`. You can add it as a decorator to `post_phrase_tokenize_processing`, or just inline it in your call to setParseAction as:

```
...
| Word(printables).setParseAction(traceParseAction(post_phrase_tokenize_processing))
...
```

EDIT:
You can get the same behavior as the updated `oneOf` using a `Regex`.

Here is the solution using plain regex:

```
import re
phrases = "ab abc def a".split()
phrases_re = re.compile(r"\b(" + '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in phrases) + r")\b" )
print(phrases_re.findall("abcd bc abc a bc def"))
['abc', 'a', 'def']
```

You can make it into a pyparsing `Regex` using this:

```
import pyparsing as pp
phrases_expr = pp.Regex(phrases_re)
print(phrases_expr.searchString("abcd bc abc a bc def"))
[['abc'], ['a'], ['def']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I updated my post to include `post_phrase_tokenize_processing`. Earlier I tried doing traseParseAction as you mentioned, and realized it was matching with basically every word, which I assumed was the time sink. Also a note - the processing is very fast for this sample text, but doesn't scale for the actual Wikipedia corpus (I left it running for a day and it wouldn't process even a single article).